# Count items in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

How do I get a count of all items in a Mongo collection, using the 2.x C# driver?

I'm trying to use CountAsync, which I need to pass in a filter. I don't want to filter - I want everything returned.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314886/getting-an-item-count-with-mongodb-c-sharp-driver-query-builder) might be helpful to you to get count.

Comment: what you got so far?

Comment: Why is this downvoted and "on hold"? It was a legitimate question one that I couldn't find answered on here.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can always pass the empty document in the method like this

```
db.collection.CountDocumentsAsync(new BsonDocument());
```

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question succinctly - except it should be BsonDocument. Can you please edit, SO won't allow me to edit it as the change is less than 6 characters.

Comment: I cannot add an answer because the question is mistakenly marked off-topic. (Mods, please unmark this question, that's stupid this is marked off-topic)

For anyone needing to do this in 2020 with the 2.9.x version of the C# driver, use the IMongoCollection.CountDocuments/IMongoCollection.CountDocumentsAsync functions instead of this.

@Devesh 's answer is still correct but deprecated.

Comment: Is this considered the quickest way to get a count of a collection?

Comment: @MaxPower yes as it will get the count from the meta data maintain by the collection

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.count()
```

In C# you can use Count() on the cursor of your collection.

Answer (score -1):

Try as below:

```
var mongo = new Mongo();
mongo.Connect();
var db = mongo.GetDatabase("DatabaseName");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Product>();
var totalCount= collection.Count();
```

you can check in the following URL
 [this  url](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87757/MongoDB-and-C)